# How can I add attributes to all characters in a folder and set them to a default value?

Tags: roll20

I recently decided to consolidate my macros that refer to a character's gender by pronoun into a single one using attributes on the character sheet (ie subjective, objective, possessiveA, and possessiveP) and am looking for a way to loop through each character in a folder and add those attributes to each of them and set them to a default of {it, it, its, and its} respectively. Is there any way I can do that? 
I do have api access if it's required to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite looping through a folder, but it does allow me to add attributes to specific characters simply by specifying a name/id or specifying that they're the currently selected token(s).

Using the ChatSetAttr API script I was able to set characters I had selected (and one I didn't have a token for but had a name for) to have the specific attributes I wanted.

For a default of {it, it, its, and its} I used the following macro to edit the ones I had selected:

```
!setattr --sel --subjective|'it'
!setattr --sel --objective|'it'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveA|'its'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveP|'its'
```

For the one I didn't have a token for I used the following to specify the correct pronouns.

```
!setattr --name Rilia --subjective|'she'
!setattr --name Rilia --objective|'her'
!setattr --name Rilia --PossessiveA|'her'
!setattr --name Rilia --PossessiveP|'hers'
```

Answer (score 3):

### You can’t

You can loop through every character with the API using filterObjs but [[t]he API does not have access to the folder structure.](https://roll20.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037772793-API-Objects#API:Objects-Handout)

Comment: So, if I can loop through every character, can I set it to exclude certain ones? That would be sufficient if so

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami sure but you can only filter based on available attributes.